# Sitecore 8.2 update 1 App Insight Configurations

Tags: azure, app-insight

I've few questions on app insight configuration with sitecore 8.2 update 1 below:

1. I assume we need to manually add the client side telemetry?
2. When I click on Server Response Time I noticed below. Is it good practice to enable this? Not sure the performance impact.

> "Enable Application Insights Profiler to collect detailed
>       performance trace".

3. What's the difference between below and examples. I would they both are same:

   a. ApplicationInsights.Tag

   b. ApplicationInsights.Role

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Correct.** Client side telemetry is normally part of layouts which are supplied with the website. Sitecore does not yet implement client-side telemetry, but we may implement relevant renderings in the future.
2. We have not tested Sitecore with Application Insights Profiler, and this is an experimental feature, so it should only be enabled during profiling sessions and should not be enabled on a permanent basis.
3. **Role** is assigned automatically when Sitecore environment is provisioned and allows to identify telemetry coming from a particular role (CM, CD, Processing, Reporting).
   **Tag** is empty by default but can be used to tag and identify telemetry coming from e.g. a staging slot